# Terminology for placeholder for elements of a set

Tags: terminology, philosophy

Let $\mathbb{X}=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ be a set and $x$ be an element of the set. Then 1 is also an element of the set. We say that $x$ is a "variable". I am searching for a word that conveys the idea of something that is an placeholder for an element of the set, but *not* a specific one (and not the entire set). I want to convey the idea of something being a schema. Compared to programming I mean something like a `class` (= placeholder/schema), in contrast to an `object` (= concrete instance) and in contrast to the set of all created `objects`.

The reason why I am hesitant to call this thing a "variable", because I do not mean the symbol, but the concept. For example, if I say $x\in\mathbb X$ and $y\in\mathbb X$, then $x$ and $y$ are *different* variables, but they are both *notate* the *same* "abstract thing for which I am searching a word for.

Another idea is to call this a universal, following

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_(metaphysics)
- or https://www.csus.edu/indiv/p/pynetf/metaphysics_toolkit.htm

> An entity is a universal if it is repeatable.  It is capable of having instances, occurrences, examples, tokens, members, cases…, whatever.  There can be more than one square, more than one blue triangle, etc.

So in this case $x$ and $y$ would denote the same universal. The universal does not convey the idea of a placeholder that much, but maybe this does not matter?

Comment: The phrase "dummy variable" (or "bound variable") springs to mind. You'd describe the symbols used as placeholders in set builder notation, limits, integrals, sigma notation, maxima/minima etc, as "dummy variables" to indicate that the specific symbol used may be swapped out for a different one without consequence.